# $0\leq n\leq 500$, $A=\{1,2,3,\cdots,500\}$ from a randomly chosen $m\in A$, the probability that $m \mid n$ is..

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Today I've encountered a question like the following;

$0\leq n \leq 500$ and $A=\{1,2,3,\cdots,500\}$ the probability that a randomly chosen $m\in A$ fully divides $n$ ($m\mid n$) is $1/100$ so what is the greatest value $n$ can get? Both $m$ and $n$ are integers.

**My Attempts**

I have named this event $U$ and $P(U)=\dfrac{1}{100}$ I know that $P(U)=\dfrac{s(U)}{s(A)}$ ($A$ is the universal set for the events right now)

So $\dfrac{s(U)}{s(A)}=\dfrac{5}{500}=\dfrac{1}{100}\implies s(U)=5$ which means that $n$ has $5$ positive divisors, which also implies due to the fact that $5$ is odd and a prime $n$ is a perfect square in form of $n=p^4$ where $p$ is a prime, so I said that the greatest $p$ would be the greatest prime in $A$ But that didn't work the answer is $3^4=81$

What are your suggestions?

Comment: No. Your argument is correct but the conclusion is wrong. The greatest $n$ will be the highest value of $p^4$ in $A$ where $p$ is a prime, which is obviously $3^4$ (the next power $5^4=625$ is greater than 500).

Comment: Thank you @PrasunBiswas, I hilariously missed this fact

Answer (score 2):

**Trying to be more formal**, number $n$ will have a prime factorisation $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdot ... \cdot p_k^{\alpha_k}$. [The number of divisor](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/tau.html)s of $n$ then is $\tau(n)=\left(\alpha_1+1\right)\cdot \left(\alpha_2+1\right)\cdot ... \cdot\left(\alpha_k+1\right)$. The probability of a random $m$ to divide $n$ is $$P=\frac{1}{100}=\frac{\tau(n)}{500} => \tau(n)=5$$
Since $5$ is prime, then we have a trivial case of $\alpha_1+1=5 \Rightarrow \alpha_1 = 4$. Then, we are looking for $n=p^4 \leq 500 < p^5$.